# Xcode installation seems corrupt?

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore

I've been try to download Xcode for work, but for some reason the Mac App Store is giving me a bit of trouble. Activity monitor shows some network usage, but in Launchpad it seems the download isn't moving.

When I go to the purchases panel of the Mac App Store, I see this.

[image: xcode problem]

No status, no pause button, in fact - the button has no text on it! I've tried restarting the App Store, restarting my computer, even removing the `com.apple.appstore` folder in `/var/folders` but alas, no luck.

Can anyone diagnose the issue? When I removed `com.apple.appstore`, Xcode still showed up on Launchpad, and clicking on it did nothing - it was frozen in time. So can I kill off this partial download and start new?

Comment: Im curious, how does the 'other purchases' area show up? As in, whats the difference between that and purchases?

Comment: @jmlumpkin I have absolutely no idea

Comment: I have the same sort of problem. What are these "other purchases" and why is the button blank and unclickable?

Comment: see this update from apple (via stackoverflow.com): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976017/how-to-upload-ipa-now-that-application-loader-is-no-longer-included-in-xcode-11

Answer (score 5):

As near as I can tell, this might be a Hidden Purchase. Choose Store > View My Account, where you can see hidden purchases. You may be able to cancel or unhide the download from there.

Comment: We have a winner! This worked to resolve the same issue I had with the Mountain Lion download.

Answer (score 2):

I always start by searching for "troubleshoot" in the help menu for the App. You will get this link:

http://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/troubleshooting/

There are several things that could be going on, but I would follow this link - that has well sequenced steps to try for a quick fix. If those don’t work, the Apple support link at the bottom is where I would ask the vendor to look at the server side or walk me through cleaning folders by hand in terminal if needed I accomplished all the steps in their document to resolve this.

- [Mac App Store: How to resume interrupted downloads](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4485)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo find /var/folders/ -ipath '*com.apple.appstore*' -print`

should show you App Store related cache files.

`sudo find /var/folders/ -ipath '*com.apple.appstore*' -print | xargs sudo fgrep -i xcode`

should show you any of those files which are related to XCode.

You could run

`sudo find /var/folders/ -ipath '*com.apple.appstore*' -delete`

which will DELETE all of the files that it finds (not just the xcode ones!) but that shouldn't be a big deal. I would expect the App Store.app would re-create any files it needs if they are not found in /var/folders/.

I ran it it did not seem to cause any problems. As always, make sure you have a complete bootable backup before running any Terminal code suggested by some stranger on the Internet :-)

Comment: I had the same symptoms and reproduced the same way as @Richard Szaley (but with a different App redeemed from the the developer center)... unfortunately this suggestion did not resolve the issue.