# View App Store Download Progress (Downloading Maverick)

Tags: mac-appstore, macos

I'm downloading Mavericks on my Lion, but I don't know how to see the progress. When I go to the purchases tab on the app store, I see a blank button:

[image: Purchases]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that it was a 'hidden' purchase, and I had to go to my account and unhide it.

Thanks to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/52868/25438).

Answer (score 0):

1. Try rebooting.
2. Quit App Store, open Launchpad, find the partial download of Mavericks installer and click it. This usually resumes a download that was interrupted/paused.
3. Reset App Store by clicking Reset Application from the debug menu, then reboot and try again.

   <sub>You can enable the debug menu by running the following command:</sub>

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't work. In fact, after I rebooted, I couldn't find the partial download.

Comment: Hmm, it's still not working. Event after resetting the app via debug menu and rebooting, the same thing (pic in original post) happens.

Comment: Open Activity Monitor and select the Network tab at the far right. Does it show any signs of any sustained network traffic in the Data received/sec display (green line)? If not, then its not downloading.

Answer (score -1):

Go to AppStore and click on Updates at the top.. You will find it.. Simple!!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.